# Why is copy constructor invoked by return statement of expression?

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing the addition operator for a custom class. The function/operator invoked is neither a friend or a member function and adds a scalar value to the vector (the class is supposed to be a linear algebra vector class). Internally, this function calls the addition operator of the class which in turn calls the compound addition of the same class.

Below is the relevant part of the declaration of the class (this is a template class) along with the implementation of the constructors, the non-member function/operator and the compound addition operator (the addition operators follow further below to show the "issue").

```
template<class T>
class Vector {
  public:
    Vector(const unsigned long length); // Default ctor
    Vector(const Vector<T>& vec); // Copy ctor

    template<class S>
    Vector<T> operator +(const S& scalar);
    
    template<class S>
    Vector<T>& operator +=(const S& scalar);

  private:
    unsigned long mLen;
    T* mData;
};

template<class T, class S>
Vector<T> operator +(const S& scalar, const Vector<T>& vec);

// Implementation of ctors
template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const unsigned long length) {
  mLen = length;
  mData = new T[length];
}

template<class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(const Vector<T>& vec) {
  mLen = vec.mLen;
  std::copy_n(vec.mData, vec.mLen, mData);
}

template<class T, class S>
Vector<T> operator +(const S& scalar, const Vector<T>& vec) {
  return vec + scalar;
}

template<class T> template<class S>
Vector<T>& Vector<T>::operator +=(const S& scalar) {
  for(unsigned long i = 0; i < mLen; ++i) {
    mData[i] += scalar;
  }

  return *this;
}
```

As already stated, the implementation is based on the compound assignment operator. All operators seem to be working as intended, result-wise, **but** when I return the result of the compound assignment operation directly the copy constructor is invoked and I can't understand why. See the following examples for clarification.

1. Example where the copy constructor is invoked

```
template<class T> template<class S>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator +(const S& scalar) {
  Vector<T> result(*this); // Normal copy ctor call
  return result += scalar; // Here the copy ctor is invoked again!!!
}
```

2. Example where the copy constructor is not invoked

```
// Implementation of the addition operators
template<class T> template<class S>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator +(const S& scalar) {
  Vector<T> result(*this); // Normal copy ctor call
  result += scalar;
  return result; // Here the copy ctor is NOT invoked
}
```

A `main.cpp` example could be the following

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  Vector<T> vec(10);
  1 + vec;
}
```

Now, when the first implementation of the addition operator is used, the copy constructor is called at the return statement (in addition to the line above which obviously makes perfect sense). When the operator is implemented in the second way, the copy constructor is only called once, when explicitly called in the above line.

I am using XCode 11.3.1 (on Mac obviously). Please let me know if you would like more information on the issue. If someone could shed some light here I would be grateful.

Comment: This is normal and expected. Return a *variable*, and you will get **named** return value optimisation. Return a *temporary*, and you won't get such optimisation, because temporaries are not named.

Comment: Are you running an optimized build?  What are the compiler settings when you built the application?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, to be honest, I am running the default setup the IDE provides and on debug. I guess that there's not much optimisation going on especially due to the debug configuration. I haven't tested on release or with optimisation flags. A nice question though whose answer I should had probably included in my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `operator+=` returns a reference, the return statement needs to copy this referenced value into the return value for the function. There is not a value available that the compiler can use to elide this call to the copy constructor.

Your first example is the equivalent of

```cpp
template<class T> template<class S>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator +(const S& scalar) {
  Vector<T> result(*this);
  Vector<T> &ans = (result += scalar);  // (Parens included for clarity)
  return ans;
}
```

which should make it more obvious why the compiler must call the copy constructor in the return statement.

The second example returns the local `result` directly, so the copy constructor call is elided.

Comment: Hhhmmm... Yes, it makes sense. The way you present it here makes it crystal-clear. Thanks for that, really appreciated.